# AS3: Variable set in one function has different value in another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

Okay I figured I better ask someone before I start tearing my hair out. I've been loading data in from an xml file, and the idea is that if loadDetails is called after the xml is loaded in it would load them on that basis and if it's called before it would set a flag which would tell the object to automatically call it again when the xml is finished. Simple, right?

```
private function parseXML(e:Event):void
{
    trace("parseXML " + mLevelID.toString(16) + "   " + mAutoload);
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    // do stuff...
    System.disposeXML(xml);
    mDetailsReady = true;
    if (mAutoload)
        loadDetails();
}

private function cancelXML(e:Event):void
{
    trace("cancelXML " + mLevelID.toString(16));
    mAutoload = false;
}

public function loadDetails():void
{
    if (!mDetailsReady)
    {
        if (!mAutoload)
            trace("autoload on " + mLevelID.toString(16));
        mAutoload = true;
        return;
    }
    if (mAutoload) trace("autoloaded " + mLevelID.toString(16));
    // do stuff...
    mAutoload = false;
}
```

Here's the problem. It's not calling loadDetails, even after the flag is set properly... or not always, anyway. Here's some sample output:

```
autoload on 0
autoload on a
autoload on 1
cancelXML 1
parseXML 0   true
autoloaded 0
parseXML a   false
```

As you can see, it traces setting mAutoload in all three levels. However, when it comes time to actually parse the xml in level a, it queries mAutoload as false and fails to autoload-- and, no, it doesn't get set as false in another function in the meanwhile, the ONLY other function that sets mAutoload to false is the constructor.

I am really confused and frustrated. I guess I'm willing to accept that this is just AS3 being ridiculous, and willing to entertain suggestions on how to bypass the problem, but right now I'm just super frustrated. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help to see more code.  Particularly, what makes the "autoloaded 0" line?  I notice that in loadDetails, the first thing you do if details are ready is set mAutoload to false.  I'm guessing the "autoloaded" line is showing that you got through loadDetails properly.  Setting it to false right there would make your `parseXML a false` line the appropriate response.

Comment: Not seeing the whole picture here.  Where are mAutoload & mDetailsReady variables being declared?  Is this in a class you're instantiating, or document code?  Are you querying these variables external to the class or internally?

Comment: Oops sorry, I removed the 'autoloaded' line when I cut out the 'do stuff' lines. I edited it back in, but it's just a trace statement immediately after the conditional block. And that would explain it, but a) that's not the case and b) it wouldn't explain why it works right for level 0 anyway. mAutoload and mDetailsReady are both private member variables, and are being used exactly as you see here: the only other usage is initialization to false for both.

Comment: Fixed the problem by calling loadDetails earlier in the main program. I don't know why that fixes it except that I suspect the problem is one of asynchronous functions sharing a resource, but it's fixed and that's good enough for me for now. It's not an answer per se, though, so I didn't put it up as one.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off

in method parseXML you do

```
mDetailsReady = true;
if (mAutoload)
    loadDetails();
```

which means mAutoload is true and mDetailsReady  is true

but in loadDetails method

```
if (!mDetailsReady)
{
    if (!mAutoload)
```

I am, not sure what you re trying to achieve with this class but if you are writing some kind of xml loader class you might want to use more of then Loader class vars to determine if it is finished loading instead of you tracking it yourself.

Comment: Sorry I think you might be getting confused by the conditionals: the "if (!mAutoload)" is just the conditional for the trace, because otherwise it often traces the same thing a bunch of times since the loading function gets called repeatedly.

The flow is like this: On instantiation the object loads its xml. If loadDetails is called before this is complete, it sets mAutoload which tells the object to call loadDetails again when the xml is parsed.

If you look at what traced out, this works properly for level 0 and cancels properly for level 1 (no xml), but works oddly on level a

Comment: "loadDetails" only gets called from one place inside "parseXML". "parseXML" once gets called from one place and that is on complete load of the xml. You seem to be reluctant to show the full class so I can't really help much other than what I have already stated. If you are infact calling "parseXML" or "loadDetails" from another area then you have a major design flaw.

Comment: Oh sorry, loadDetails is called externally. Why is this a major design flaw? And I don't mind showing the class, but most of it is irrelevant and altogether is 500+ lines

Comment: This is not an AS3 issue this is purely a logic flaw in your code. I would suggest you refactor your class and create an encapsulated class that handles just the loading of the xml. Once you do that then you can just make it event driven to populate your data.

Comment: What is the logic flaw? Why is it behaving differently between level 0 and level a? And what do you suggest for making it 'event driven'? I could easily have loadDetails called by parseXML, but I don't because that would basically load all game assets concurrently.

Comment: Like the other comments from the other guys, you didn't post enough code for me to even begin to diagnose the flaw. The best I can tell you is the flow logic is flawed. But again I would suggest you encapsulate and load data async and just work off of events to populate data.

Comment: The code I've posted contains every usage of the member variables mAutoload and mDetailsReady outside of the constructor. If there was more I would show you. I can put up a screenshot of the text search if it would make you feel better. Assume that loadDetails is called a million bajillion times a second and this STILL makes no sense. You're saying the flow is flawed because that's more likely from your perspective than a mistake in AIR, but it ain't from mine. I guess I'll see if I can find a workaround then.